# Setting the textarea in a GridView after DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set the textarea of the gridview which has a Datatable:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTemplateFields" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Risk">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <textarea id="Risk"
                    cols="20" rows="2"
                    runat="server"
                    style="width: 99%">
                </textarea>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No off-site links found.</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

The data binding:

```
DataTable templateFields = SWMSField.GetTemplateFields(TemplateId);
gvTemplateFields.DataSource = templateFields;
gvTemplateFields.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ASP.NET server control instead:-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Risk">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="Risk" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="20" Rows="2" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Eval("RiskColumn")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here, `RiskColumn` is the column name which holds the data you want to bind in textarea.

Comment: we can also put value for HTML server control. Like
 `<textarea id="Risk"
                    cols="20" rows="2"
                    runat="server"
                    style="width: 99%" value='<%# Eval("RiskColumn")%>'>
                </textarea>` As `runat="server"` make HTML control to work like server side control.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo - Yes we can :)